# Proving $M_p$ is maximal in $C[0,1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

Let $M_p$ be the ideal of those continuous functions of $C[0,1]$ which have $p\in [0,1]$ as a zero. It is a commonly known fact that $M_p$ is a maximal ideal. However, the proof is generally non-trivial. I was wondering if the proof I am about to present is accurate. I feel it is much simpler than the one books generally prescribe, and hence there must be something wrong in it.

Let $f(x)\notin M_p$. Hence $f(p)=c$, where $c\neq 0$. Clearly, the continuous function $g(x)=(f(x)-c)\in M_p$. Now $f(x)-g(x)=c\in (M_p,f(x))$, which is a unit. Hence, $(M_p,f(x))=R$

Is the proof correct?

The proof books generally give: Let $f(x)\notin M_p$. Then for any $g(x)\in M_p$, where the only zero of $g(x) \in [0,1]$ is $p$, $f^2+g^2\notin M_p$, and also a unit. Hence, $(M_p,f(x))=R$. I have seen this proof in multiple books.

Comment: You are correct. But this is not the hard part of the characterisation. The non-trivial statement is usually ... *all* maximal ideals of $C[0,1]$ are of the form $M_p$.

Comment: I am not sure which proof you have seen. Noting that the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (with an obvious map) seems pretty easy to me.

Comment: Yes. In other words, $C([0,1])/M_p \cong \mathbb{C}$ (or $\cong \mathbb{R}$ if you're considering only real-valued functions), so $C([0,1])/M_p$ is a field, hence $M_p$ is maximal. What proof do the books generally give?

Comment: @DanielFischer- I have edited the question with the proof books generally give. I feel constructing $f^2+g^2$ is less straightforward than my proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer- Sorry $g(x)$ has the special property that its only zero in $[0,1]$ is $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof *is* trivial. If $X$ is any space, $p \in X$ and $C(X)$ is the ring of (say) $\mathbb{C}$-valued continuous functions on $X$, then $C(X) \to \mathbb{C}$, $f \mapsto f(p)$ is a ring homomorphism (clear) which is surjective (consider constant functions) and the kernel is (by definition) $M_p$. Hence $C(X)/M_p \cong \mathbb{C}$ is a field, i.e. $M_p$ is maximal.

(The mentioned proof in freebird's question just repeats the characterization of maximal ideals by quotient rings.)